# matrix multipication in c

Tags: c, void, matrix-multiplication

i know there are similiar questions but i tried the suggestions there and it still does not work, here my complete code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void ludec(int N, double lu[N][N]){
    double temp;
    int k,i,j;
    for(k=0;k<N;k++){
        for(i=k+1;i<N;i++){
            temp=lu[i][k]/=lu[k][k];
            for(j=k+1;j<N;j++){
                lu[i][j]-=temp*lu[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
void matmul(int u,int m,int n,double p[u][m],double bb[m][n]){
    double mul[u][n];

    int ii,jj,kk;
    for(ii=0;ii<u;ii++){
        for(jj=0;jj<n;jj++){
            mul[ii][jj]=0.0;
        }
    }
    for(ii=0;ii<u;ii++){
        for(jj=0;jj<n;jj++){
            for(kk=0;kk<m;kk++){
                mul[ii][jj]=mul[ii][jj]+p[ii][kk]*bb[kk][jj];
                printf("la %f ii %d jj%d kk%d\n",mul[ii][jj],ii,jj,kk);
            }
        }
    }

}

int main(void){
    double lu[3][3]={{4.0,3.0,-2.0},{-1.0,-1.0,3.0},{2.0,-1.0,5.0}};
    double a[3][3]={{4.0,3.0,-2.0},{-1.0,-1.0,3.0},{2.0,-1.0,5.0}};
    double y[3][1];
    double b[3][1]={{9.0},{-4.0},{6.0}};
    double x[3][1];
    int i,j,N=3;
    double f=0;
    ludec(N, lu);
    y[0][0]=b[0][0];
    for(i=1;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
             f+=lu[i][j]*y[j][0];

         }
         y[i][0]=(b[i][0]-f);
         f=0;
     }
     f=0;



     x[2][0]=y[2][0]/lu[2][2];
     for(i=1;i>=0;i--){

        for(j=1+i;j<3;j++){
             f+=lu[i][j]*x[j][0];

        }
         x[i][0]=(y[i][0]-f)/lu[i][i];
         f=0;

     }
     printf("%f\n %f\n %f\n",x[0][0],x[1][0],x[2][0]);      
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%f %d %d\n",lu[i][j],i,j);
        }
    }



    double mul[3][1];
    matmul(3,3,1,a,x);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("%f %d %d\n",mul[i][j],i,j);
        }
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

here is the part responsible by multiplication;
the problem is
i have to get 3*1 matrix as result in matrix multiplication, but it gives bigger matrix with alot of garbage elements i monitor the matrix multiplication by printf in the matmul function and it seems to work but when i do same out side the matmul function it gives garbage only some values are correct with a lot of useless wrong elements.

```
void matmul(int u,int m,int n,double p[u][m],double bb[m][n]){
        double mul[u][n];

    int ii,jj,kk;
    for(ii=0;ii<u;ii++){
        for(jj=0;jj<n;jj++){
            mul[ii][jj]=0.0;
        }
    }
    for(ii=0;ii<u;ii++){
        for(jj=0;jj<n;jj++){
            for(kk=0;kk<m;kk++){
                mul[ii][jj]=mul[ii][jj]+p[ii][kk]*bb[kk][jj];
                printf("la %f ii %d jj%d kk%d\n",mul[ii][jj],ii,jj,kk);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is matmul function and i dont know why it does not work i already initialized the matrix with zeros. am i using void function property wrong?
i am very new to c hence there may be something i am doing wrong. the overall code is for lu decompositation, and i want to see wheter the code works or not by multiplying result with initial matrix.

[this is the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg575.png)

Comment: I think you should be more specific than "it does not work".

Comment: i have to get 3*1 matrix as result in matrix multiplication, but it gives bigger matrix with alot of garbage elements i monitor the matrix multiplication by printf  in the matmul function and it seems to work but when i do same out side the matmul function it gives garbage only some values are correct with a lot of useless wrong elements.

Comment: @physshyp you should add that information to the question. You can [edit] your own question.

Comment: Please insert spaces around binary operators, it will make your code so much easier to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mul` is a local variable in `matmul`, thus the result is not visible to the calling function.  You should modify the `matmul` function to take the result matrix as an argument:

```
void matmul(int u, int m, int n,
            double mul[u][n], const double p[u][m], const double bb[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            mul[i][j] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                mul[i][j] += p[i][k] * bb[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke from `main` as

```
    double mul[3][1];
    matmul(3, 3, 1, mul, a, x);
```

And print the output vector:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        printf("%f %d %d\n", mul[i][j], i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,  at the end mul should be {{9},{-4},{6}} but when i scan it from j=0 to 5 and i=0 to 5 first three elements are correct then i get 4 and repition of elements what is the reason of that?

Comment: i add the out put as a image to my question

Comment: i still get element in mul[2][4] ect. that i shouldn't .

Comment: There is no element `mul[2][4]`, `mul` is `3x1`, accessing non existing elements of `mul` is undefined behaviour.  This means that it can cause your program to crash, have erratic behaviour or just produce garbage values as it seems to do.  Your output code is incorrect as already mentioned in a previous response, I modified the response to show a fixed version.